# Uncheck radio button using JQuery function

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following dynamic radio button generated by php

```js
echo '<div class="col-sm" id="currentOa'.$loop.'Div" >
      <input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="currentOa'.$loop.'" value="currentOa'.$loop.'">
     </div>';
```

I have the following JQuery function that will do unchecking of radio button if some other value (`$('#oaInShift' + shiftNumber).val()`) in the form is empty. Take note that the following function is called from an onChange radio button event. The `else` condition in working fine in this function. Only the `if` part not working

```js
function radioCheck(shiftNumber) {
  if ($('#oaInShift' + shiftNumber).val() == "") { 
    $('#currentOa' + shiftNumber).checked = false; 
  } else {
    $("#currentOaSelected").val($('#oaInShift' + shiftNumber).val());
  }
}
```

I tried the following way too. But it is not working as well

```js
$('#currentOa' + shiftNumber).prop("checked", "false");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues. You can use

```
$("#id").prop("checked", true);
```

Notice false here boolean value. Other thing you can refactor, Instead of using id you can use class which is safer. Because, You can't have more than one id in one window. Otherwise, you might get issue like this.

```
echo '<div class="col-sm currentOa'.$loop.'Div">
      <input type="radio" name="currentOa" class="currentOa'.$loop.'" value="currentOa'.$loop.'">
     </div>';
```

Than code to access:

```
   $(".classname").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Thanks @xdeepakv. I am able to solve it with `id` itself by changing `"false"` to `false`